# Method for finding branch points, branch cuts and branches of a function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

Is this a good approach $?$:

1. Find branch points by considering where the function is undefined e.g $\sqrt{z(z-1)}$ is undefined at $=0$ and $=1$.
2. Restrict domain of $ℂ$ so that we can't draw a closed path around the branch points, this defines a branch cut, i.e the complement of this restricted set of points.
3. Then we can define a branch from here by defining the function on the restricted domain $?$.

I however discovered that in the example
$$
f(z) = \sqrt{z(z-1)},
$$
we can define a branch of $f$ on
$$
\mathbb{C}\setminus(-\infty,0) \cup (1, \infty),
$$
and this clearly goes against my above reasoning, why can we do this $?$.

My reasoning leads to the conclusion that we can define a branch on $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$, however I am not sure why we can get one on the other interval.

Comment: I guess it’s better to consider $\displaystyle \sqrt{z}\,\sqrt{z - 1}$. The first has a branch-cut along $\left(-\infty,0\right]$ while the second has one along $\left(-\infty,1\right]$. So, “Divide and conquer” trick !!!.

Comment: Your step $1$ is incorrectly stated.  Clearly, $\sqrt{z(z-1)}$ is defined at $z=0$ and $z=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The whole purpose of a branch cut is to keep your complex function $f(z)$ single valued so that you can apply the wonderful theorems associated with holomorphic functions. Because any complex number $z$ can be written as $z = z_0 + re^{i\theta}=z_0 + re^{i\theta + 2\pi i}$, your function can become multivalued when you wind around a *single* branch point. However, if your function has two or more branch points, this doesn't necessarily mean that winding around two branch points simultaneously will lead to trouble.

For the function $f(z) = \sqrt{z(z-1)}$, you are right that there are branch points at $z = 0$ and $z = 1$. As you pointed out, there are two potential branch cuts you can use $\mathbb{C}\setminus[0,1]$ and $\mathbb{C}\setminus(0,-\infty) \cup \mathbb{C}\setminus(1,\infty)$. To see why winding around both points doesn't cause a problem, note that for any $z \in \mathbb{C}$, we can write $z = r_1e^{i\theta_1}$ and $z = 1 + r_2e^{i\theta_2}$ for some $r_1,r_2 \ge 0$ and $\theta_1,\theta_2 \in [0,2\pi)$. Therefore, we can write
$$f(z) = \sqrt{r_1e^{i\theta_1}r_2e^{i\theta_2}} = \sqrt{r_1r_2}e^{i\frac{\theta_1}{2}}e^{i\frac{\theta_2}{2}}.$$
Now, if we loop around both $z = 0$ and $z = 1$, then $\theta_1 \to \theta_1 + 2\pi $ and $\theta_2\to \theta_2 + 2\pi$ and we have
$$\sqrt{r_1r_2}e^{i\frac{\theta_1 + 2\pi}{2}}e^{i\frac{\theta_2 + 2\pi}{2}} = \sqrt{r_1r_2}e^{i\frac{\theta_1}{2}}e^{i\frac{\theta_2}{2}}e^{2\pi i} = \sqrt{r_1r_2}e^{i\frac{\theta_1}{2}}e^{i\frac{\theta_2}{2}} = f(z)$$
so the function stays single-valued. However, let's see what happens when we loop around only one of the branch points. Let's try looping around just $z = 0$. Then we have that $\theta_1 \to \theta_1 + 2\pi$ but $\theta_2 \to \theta_2$ since we aren't looping around $z = 1$. Then our function becomes
$$\sqrt{r_1r_2}e^{i\frac{\theta_1 + 2\pi}{2}}e^{i\frac{\theta_2}{2}} = \sqrt{r_1r_2}e^{i\frac{\theta_1}{2}}e^{i\frac{\theta_2}{2}}e^{i\pi} = -f(z)$$
and hence the function becomes multivalued. Thus we can see that the purpose of our branch cut here is to prevent us from winding around a single branch point. Winding around both branch points does not cause a problem. Obviously the branch cut $\mathbb{C}\setminus(0,-\infty) \cup \mathbb{C}\setminus(1,\infty)$ prevents us from winding around either of the points $z=0$ or $z = 1$ so it works as well.

Comment: That is a great explanation of things, thank you.

Comment: Interestingly, the branch cut $\mathbb{C}\setminus(0,-\infty) \cup \mathbb{C}\setminus(1,\infty)$ connects the points $0$ and $1$ on the Riemannn sphere.

Comment: I actually realised I fail to understand why looping around just one branch point causes this issue, why does $\theta_2$ fail to change by $2\pi$?

Comment: @mosthigh Because in the second example we do not loop around $z = 1$, we only loop around $z = 0$.

Comment: Why does this fail to change $\theta_2$ to $\theta_2 + 2\pi$? I'm really confused.